# Who particpated In formal musical grading education in England?

Tags: learning, musicology

England has produced some very successful musicians in the popular music field in the past five decades. Elton John, The Beatles, The Stones, The Moody Blues, and countless others. But in the U.S. we never hear about whether any of them participated in the English grading system, or how far they may have advanced in that system. Can anybody give a little light on this?

Comment: My guess is very very few. In the '60s there were 'classical' type piano exams - as there were in a lot of other orchestral instruments, but only classical guitar grades. That wouldn't have helped the Beatles et al, and they probably wouldn't have been inclined anyway.

Comment: A lot of the musicians you list didn't really have much formal music education. That wasn't really a requirement to be a musician in their time, and it still isn't really. I'm sure there have been lots of English musicians, though, who have received training in the English grading system.

Comment: This is actually off topic here, but maybe you could ask on Music Fans.